# Where is the steam authorization file?

Tags: steam

My steam installation was having some weird problems, so I "reinstalled" steam by deleting everything EXCEPT:

**steamapps/**

**userdata/**

**Steam.exe**

This caused steam to redownload all its files. On launch I get the login prompt, I type in my authentication details, but when I click `Login`, Steam asks to authorize my machine.

My old steam files are still in my trash bin. What is the "authorization file" called? I want to copy it back to my current steam folder. I don't think this action should cause problems since it's the same machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Steam Authorisation file is the two `ssfn[Some Numbers]` (Steam Sentry File) found in the base folder.

When switching auth files, ensure that you copy **both** `ssfn*` files.
*One of them is a hidden file.*

[image: SSFN Files - Contents hidden for security reasons.]

---

**Warning:** This file can be used to bypass all two-factor authentication, so **keep it safe** and DO NOT give it to anybody (not even upload it anywhere).
*To be on the safe side, don't make any backups of it. Besides, you can always generate a new one with a new installation of Steam.*

Comment: The Non-Hidden file is only a fake - a simple distraction to make it harder to phish people into uploading their sentry file. It always has the same static content.

Comment: It used to be real, this answer is out of date, which is why many idiots got hacked (phished).

Comment: I searched the Steam Authorization files but in my Steam folder there no ssfn<numbers> files. I also used UltraSearch and searched my complete C: drive but it couldn't find any files starting with ssfn.

Comment: @T137 It's no longer used; it doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is probably too old. I don't have any ssfn* files. To retain logins I had to copy
`%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\config` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Steam\local.vdf`.

Comment: The only useful file in the config folder seems to be `loginusers.vdf`, which has minimal info about the most recent user and won't auto-login after destroying the rest of the data. And `local.vdf` is just a cache of Steam servers it's used recently and presumably would try first for the next connection. If they finally fixed this that's a great change, despite slightly screwing up the "Steam client clean up" directions.